# Binary Search Output giving wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

This is my code:

```
def binary_search(keys, query):
    low, high = 0, 0
    while low <= high:
        midpoint = low + (high - low) // 2
        if query == keys[midpoint]:
            return midpoint
        elif keys[midpoint] > query:
            high = midpoint - 1 
        else:
            low = midpoint + 1
    return -1       
           

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_keys = int(input())
    input_keys = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(input_keys) == num_keys

    num_queries = int(input())
    input_queries = list(map(int, input().split()))
    assert len(input_queries) == num_queries

    for q in input_queries:
        print(binary_search(input_keys, q), end=' ')
```

I am inputting:

```
5
1 5 8 12 13
5
8 1 23 1 11
```

I should be getting this as output:

```
2 0 -1 0 -1
```

but I am getting this instead:

```
-1 0 -1 0 -1
```

Comment: 0 doesn't seem particularly high to me.

Comment: What is the goal of your code?

Comment: @RichardKYu It's [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: it is a binary search and as soon as I posted I figure out my mistake, thanks @Selcuk and Chris for helping out. I had to choose the right answer so I am just putting my finger on one of them. thanks no hard feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting with both `low` and `high` equal to `0`, which doesn't make sense. Change the first two lines to the following:

```
low, high = 0, len(keys)
while low < high:
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when you're looking for `8` in `1 5 8 12 13`.

`low` and `high` start out as `0` and `0`, respectively. `midpoint` therefore is `0`.

`keys[midpoint]` is `1`.

This is less than `query`, which is `8`. Thus `low` is set to `1`. `low` is now greater than `high` so the loop ends, and the function returns `-1`.